# How to reverse longitude/latitude of point in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How could I reverse the order to normal (latitude, longitude) for my geography line string that has multiple points in the column?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use link to images to show the SQL. Just include it as text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a numbers table, you can do this. It's not the most elegant thing I've ever written, but it gets the job done.

```
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY, @g_new GEOGRAPHY, @t VARCHAR(200);
SET @g = geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING (2 1,4 3)', 4236);
SELECT  @g.ToString();

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT   [n] ,
            @g.[STPointN]([n]) AS [point]
    FROM     [Util].[dbo].[Numbers] AS [n]
    WHERE    [n] <= @g.[STNumPoints]()
)

SELECT  @t = CONCAT('LINESTRING(', 
    STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(',', [cte].[point].Lat, ' ', [cte].[point].Long)
        FROM [cte]
        ORDER BY n
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1, 1, ''), 
    ')'
);

SET @g_new = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(@t, @g.[STSrid]);
SELECT @g_new.ToString();
```